# Filter exported data cloudFormation using aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, command-line-interface, aws-cloudformation, jq

I want to filter the exported output values of this command `aws cloudformation list-exports` using **jq** or **query**.

Example of Data:

```
     {
        "Exports": [
            {
                "ExportingStackId": "arn:aws...",
                "Name": "RSC-NAME-2",
                "Value": "RSC-VALUE-2"
            },
            {
                "ExportingStackId": "arn:aws...",
                "Name": "My-RSC-NAME",
                "Value": "My-RSC-VALUE"
            }
        ]
    }
```

I'm looking for a command that can return the **Value** and filter by **Name**

Example: if i search by **Name** equal to `My-RSC-NAME` the result will be `My-RSC-VALUE`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can easily do with native --query

> aws cloudformation list-exports --query
> "Exports[?Name=='ThisIsNameOfExport'].Value"  --output text

Answer (score 1):

Using jq:

```
.Exports[] | select(.Name == "My-RSC-NAME").Value
```